# How to express that a set of two points has to be included in two sets, one in each.

Tags: general-topology

I have two sets of locations, and they are disjoint. I also have a set that includes start and stop location. How do I express with set operators that the start and stop locations must be included in the two disjoint set, but only one in each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location sets A,B;  a = start, b = stop.
$A \cap B$ = empty set;
$a \in A, b \in B$ or $b \in A, a \in B$.